# Discord allow uploading from hidden directories

Tags: permissions, snap, hidden-files

I've found in my discord (installed from snap) that it cannot access hidden folders (ex. `~/.minecraft`). Is there a way to give discord permissions to upload files from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's a feature of snap confinement to prevent applications getting access to things like your gpg or ssh credentials.

Copy the file to somewhere else like ~/Documents then upload it.

Comment: God-awful answer